# Add to query in order to get total sum of previous results SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a query that provides the result set below, I now need to add to this query to provide a total at the bottom of all the sales. I am not sure how to do this.

Current query:

```
SELECT
    product,
    COUNT(OrderNumber) AS CountOf
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    STATUS = 'booking' AND
    Date(OrderDate) <= CURDATE() AND 
    Date(OrderDate) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)

GROUP BY
    product
ORDER BY CountOf DESC
```

Current Resultset:

```
product| count
-----------------------
pd1  | 3
pd4  | 1
pd2  | 1
```

desired result set =

```
product| count
-----------------------
pd1  | 3
pd4  | 1
pd2  | 1
Total | 5
```

Comment: If I knew what that was would I have asked the question?

Comment: Does it matter? Now you know.

Comment: It errors when I use it, so that isn't the solution

Comment: Did you use it like [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)?  Post how you tried `WITH ROLLUP` so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can add a UNION, and a SELECT with total amount. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    product,
    COUNT(OrderNumber) AS CountOf
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    STATUS = 'booking' AND
    Date(OrderDate) <= CURDATE() AND 
    Date(OrderDate) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY
    product
UNION
SELECT 'Total', count(OrderNumber) AS CountOf
FROM   orders
WHERE
    STATUS = 'booking' AND
    Date(OrderDate) <= CURDATE() AND 
    Date(OrderDate) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
ORDER BY CountOf DESC;
```

Comment: I get an incorrect usage or union and order by error?

Comment: @LewisSmith Thank you, I have edited my post. Now total will be ordered at top (instead at end). But I think it's ok as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Inner join on the same table, the union did not work due to there being the incorrect amount of columns on each side.

The Initial select had 2 set columns, where the second select (after the union) did not.